# CascadeDelete cycle error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

Hi everyone I am trying to enable cascade delete but it gives an error which says :

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Images_dbo.Content_Content_Id' on table 'Images' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Here is my images class and content class :

```
public class Content
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string PreInfo { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string scopedText { get; set; }
    public virtual Institution Instutition { get; set; }
    public Boolean News { get; set; }
    public Boolean Announcement { get; set; }
    public DateTime Create { get; set; }
    public virtual Member Who { get; set; }
    public short Row { get; set; }
    public virtual ContentArea ContentArea { get; set; }
    public Boolean Approvel { get; set; }
    public Boolean Slider { get; set; }
    public string  Image { get; set; }
    public Boolean popularNews { get; set; }
    public Boolean popularByTgsp { get; set; }
    public Boolean sliderByTgsp { get; set; }
    public Boolean Canceled { get; set; }       
}

public class Images
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ResimBuyuk { get; set; }
    public string ResimKucuk { get; set; }
    public short Sira { get; set; }
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
    public virtual Institution Institution { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectArea ProjectArea { get; set; }
    public virtual ContentArea ContentArea { get; set; }
    public virtual EventArea EventArea { get; set; }
    public virtual ServiceArea ServiceArea { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
    public virtual Content Content { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public Boolean EventAreaImage { get; set; }
    public Boolean ProjectAreaImage { get; set; }       
}
```

and here is fluent

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Images>()
    .HasOptional<Content>(s => s.Content)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

what could be the solution to enable cascadeDelete ?

Comment: Are you sure this is the only `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)` relevant to either of these entities? I would think it's not based on the error.

Comment: no that is not only one there are more for other tables as well as Service Institution but they work

Comment: If you read the message, it says "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths". That means if you have entities A, B and C, you can't configure "On Delete A => Delete B and C. On Delete B => Delete C". The reason is that if you delete A, C would be in two cascade paths. That's why I'm saying you need to check the other entities, even though you say they work. While they work by themselves, they cause conflicts.

Comment: Yea I checked and decided to warn user that they should delete data in other tables cuz cascade cant go for a=> b =>c without good query. thank you so much mate